# editing specific dictionary in file

Tags: python-3.x, file, dictionary

```
def update(login_info):
    stids = login_info[1].strip() # stids can be any , but in my case is 001

    print()
    print("  1 - Add a course              ".center(40))
    print("  2 - Update a course mark      ".center(40))
    x = int(input('Pls select your option >> '))
    if x == 1:
        regis = input("Pls Enter the code of the course >> ") # just an example
        mark = input("Pls enter your marks >> ") # file can be any name 
        up = mark.upper()
    elif x == 2:
        pass
```

so how do I access the particular dictionary that stored in the file with the stids : 001 let's say if x == 1: user will be able to add another course and mark  behind the existing data.this main point of this question is how to access to the particular dictionary with specific value.(in my case is 001)

[Dictionaries stored in file ][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQAr8.png

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing the data and the code that  produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.  ***Note:*** please provide an example of ```login_info```

Comment: i mentioned in my question, stids is 001

Comment: u can simply just def update() without haveing login_info

Comment: When you say STID are you referring to a Service Type Identifier?  If yes, we need more information regarding the specific type of application supplying the stid

Comment: stids(student id) , it can be any number, the problem is how do I  modify the dictionary with stids: 001 in mycase

Comment: What does the file look like?  Where is it stored?  What is the file name associated with stids 001?